# Known facts about factorization of p-1 for prime p.

Tags: number-theory

Specifically, I am wondering if it is known if there are infinitely many prime $p$ so that $p-1$ = $2q$ for a prime $q$. Even better if $q$ is 3 or 7 mod 8. However, I can probably work with less, so what are known facts of the nature there are infinitely many prime $p$ so that $p-1$ factors nicely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're asking if there are infinitely many Sophie Germain primes, which is an open problem. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime).

The only fact about $q$ I could find was that if you have $2q+1$ prime with $q>3$ also prime, then $q \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, which is fairly obvious.